# Webpack: No template for dependency: CssDependency

Tags: javascript, html, css, webpack

Есть небольшой проект на вебпаке 5.4.0. Его структура:

- dist
- node_modules
- src

  - css
  - fonts
  - images
  - js
  - index.js
  - template.html
- package.json
- package-lock.json
- webpack.config.js

При запуске проекта в dev-режиме появляется следующая ошибка:

```js
ERROR in   Error: Child compilation failed:
  No template for dependency: CssDependency:
  Error: No template for dependency: CssDependency
  CodeGenerationError: No template for dependency: CssDependency

  - Compilation.js:2155
    [project1]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:2155:20

  - CacheFacade.js:51
    [project1]/[webpack]/lib/CacheFacade.js:51:43

  - Cache.js:91
    [project1]/[webpack]/lib/Cache.js:91:34

  - MemoryCachePlugin.js:45 Array.<anonymous>
    [project1]/[webpack]/lib/cache/MemoryCachePlugin.js:45:13

  - Cache.js:91
    [project1]/[webpack]/lib/Cache.js:91:19
 
 ...
 
 - Hook.js:18 Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync]
    [project1]/[tapable]/lib/Hook.js:18:14

  - Compiler.js:1010
    [project1]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:1010:33

  - Compilation.js:2029
    [project1]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:2029:10


  - Hook.js:18 Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync]
    [project1]/[tapable]/lib/Hook.js:18:14

  - Compilation.js:2022
    [project1]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:2022:37



webpack 5.4.0 compiled with 1 error in 132 ms
i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

Конфликтующих лоадеров вроде как нет, для sass/css стоят MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, css-loader, sass-loader. Пробовал разные их комбинации, даже со style-loader'ом (хотя его не рекомендуют использовать для dev-режима). Вот пример вебпак-конфига и package.json:

```js
const path = require('path');
const devMode = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',

  output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: '',
  },

  mode: 'development',
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
        contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
        open: true,
        compress: true,
        hot: true,
        port: 8008,
    },

  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'webpack Boilerplate',
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/template.html'),
      filename: 'index.html',
    })
  ],

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.css'],
    modules: [
      'node_modules'
    ]        
},

  module: {
  
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: 'html-loader'
      },

      {
        test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
        use: [          
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: { sourceMap: true }
          }, 
          {
            loader: "sass-loader",
            options: { sourceMap: true }
          }
        ]

      },
     
      {
        test: /\.(ttf|eot|png|img|jpg|ico|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
        loader: 'file-loader'
      },
      
    ],
    
  },
  
};
```

```js
{
  "name": "project1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "private": true,
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "webpack --watch",
    "build": "webpack",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^5.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "html-loader": "^1.3.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^1.3.1",
    "sass": "^1.29.0",
    "sass-loader": "^10.1.0",
    "webpack": "^5.4.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.2",
    "source-map": "^0.7.3"
  }
}
```

Сборка проекта также валится с похожей ошибкой. Перелопатил весь SO, issues на гитхабе в репозитории вебпака, но ни один метод из предложенных не помог. В чём может быть дело?

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, это не ваш сценарий, но у меня была такая же ошибка при использовании монорепозитория на базе lerna

```
-- packages
---- packageA
------ webpack.config.js
---- packageB
------ webpack.config.js
-- webpack.utils.js
-- webpack.config.js
```

Файл webpack.utils.js содержал общий код лоадеров для пакетов, включая MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader. Корневой webpack.config.js импортировал конфиги из каждого пакета и запускал общую сборку.

Проблема возникала, когда один из пакетов имел свою зависимость mini-css-extract-plugin и подключал плагин из своих node_modules. Таким образом, лоадер был импортирован из корневого node_module, а сам плагин - из node_modules конкретного пактета. Решилось удалением зависимости.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, this error was caused by the fact that I mistakenly connected the CSS file to the root index.html using the link tag while also using Webpack with MiniCSSExtractPlugin. There must be no CSS file link in the html file when you're using Webpack.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! переведите, пожалуйста, текст ответа (нажав [edit] ниже текста ответа) на русский язык